# How to use one-click to click multiple same class name with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an HTML :

```
<div class ='a'>
   Click here to more info-1
</div>
<div class ='a'>
   Click here to more info-2
</div>
....
<div class ='a'>
   Click here to more info-1000
</div>
```

I used `click()` to click each class, it's mean: I click `Click here to more info-1` after I click `Click here to more info-2` and so on.

But I have 1000 `class ='a'` and if I use my solution, I will need 1000 times click.

I want to know how to click 1000 `class ='a'` in **one time** with **one-click**

**My code**

```
auto_click = broswer.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class="a"]')
while len(auto_click) >=1:
   for i in auto_click:     
      browser_movie.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", i)
      i.click()
   auto_click = broswer.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class="a"]')
```

Comment: you can use for loop

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the selenium code you've written to address your issue?

Comment: @HamzaLachi My solution use loop to click one time - one class

Comment: @orde I updated

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are trying to do.  Are you saying you want to execute 1000 clicks all at the same time?

Comment: @orde yes, this is that I want